# How do I burn Windows 10 iso from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, iso

I was wondering how one can do bootable Windows 10 USB stick from Ubuntu. I have the file `Win10_1909_EnglishInternational_x64.iso` in the directory `/home/jaakko/Downloads`. But the startup disc creator gives OS Version Ubuntu. When I click other and select the Windows iso and double click the file, the `Source disk image (.iso):` shows still the file `/home/jaakko/Download/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`. Is this a bug or why won't the disk creator show Windows 10?

Comment: I have used **`woeusb`** in text mode successfully according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185) with current Windows 10 files (latest time a couple of weeks ago). -- The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator uses the cloning method, and it does not work with Windows 10 iso files. Furthermore, that tool 'does not want to' work with iso files that are not Ubuntu iso files or look like Ubuntu iso files.

Comment: I don't know what startup-disk-creator is, but is sound to specialised. You don't want to create a disk image. You just need to write the one that you have. Use a CD image burner.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor. Maybe I did not explain clearly what I meant in my previous comment: The cloning method does not work with Windows 10 iso files to make a USB boot drive. -- If the user has a DVD drive and the iso file is small enough, a DVD image burner, for example `k3b`, is a good alternative. Otherwise booting from a USB pendrive is the remaining alternative, and `woeusb` is an extracting tool, that can do the job.

Comment: @sudodus No your comment is clear, however I was not responding to it. I was responding to guest's question. It seems that you know that startup-disk-creator is not the correct tool. However the person that wrote the question does not.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, OK. Do you want that I remove my second (and third) comments?

Answer (score 3):

The current situation with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has changed since this question was asked, commented and answered.

**woeusb** is not yet working with this new version of Ubuntu, but there are alternatives.

- Until this problem with `woeusb` is solved, you can use **mkusb** that is decribed at this link:

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/)

  The tool **`mkusb-tow`** is doing the job in mkusb version 12.5.6 and newer versions). See this link:

  [mkusb 12.5.6 with new installer for Windows](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13961108#post13961108)

---

- A set of workaround commands for woeusb in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is described in the following link,

  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243564/how-can-i-create-windows-bootable-usb-for-old-systems-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-foss

---

- You can **do it yourself** with detailed help at

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files)

  This method works in both BIOS and UEFI mode and also with secure boot. (But in most cases it should be possible to turn off secure boot, use the drive created by `woeusb`, and turn on secure boot again.)

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/)
1. Format the usb into MBR/DOS or GPT
2. Create FAT-partition (or for files > 4GB exFAT)
3. Use disk image mounter to mount .iso file
4. copy-paste all files of the mounted image onto usb device

Alternative
use [**woeusb**](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB)

Sorry for long answer instead of the link, but my reputation is still low.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Windows 10 ISO image is also suitable for USB media without any changes.  In that case, the steps are as follows:

1. Insert the flash drive.
2. Figure out what device the flash drive is.  Don't guess here, since choosing the wrong device means you'll overwrite your hard drive.  If the drive is mounted, run `mount` to see what the last line is, and pick the device portion of that (e.g., `/dev/sdb` if the line starts with something like `/dev/sdb1`).  If it's not mounted, run `dmesg` (with `sudo` if necessary), scroll to the end, and find the entry for the device that starts with `sd` (`sdb` in the given example).
3. If your device is listed in the `mount` output, unmount it by running `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` (assuming that was what was listed).
4. Run `dd if=/home/jaakko/Downloads/Win10_1909_EnglishInternational_x64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`, replacing `/dev/sdb` with the device you discovered in step 2 (without the digit on the end).
5. Run `sync` and wait until it finishes.

That will write the data to disk, and then you can use it as a normal bootable flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply installing Virtualbox from the Ubuntu store, installed a quick Windows 10 VM, and burned my ISO from there using Rufus.

That was the most frictionless method for me, while using a little detour.

Works like a charm, until woeusb dependency issues are resolved I can go to that native solution.

At the same time, you get to learn some Virtualbox, which might come in handy to any Ubuntu user.